# как добавить собственную переменную в функцию в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу чтобы при вызове функции "random" бот выводил одно из предложений, но при таком коде пишется ошибка "q is a required argument that is missing."

```
@client.command()
async def random(ctx,q):
    q=random.randint(0,2)
    if q==0:
        await ctx.send("Вы проиграли, выпало 0")
    elif q==1:
        await ctx.send("Вы выиграли, выпало 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы решить этот вопрос я импортировал "random" в саму функцию.

```
@client.command()
async def random(ctx,q):
    import random
    q=random.randint(0,2)
    if q==0:
        await ctx.send("Вы проиграли, выпало 0")
    elif q==1:
        await ctx.send("Вы выиграли, выпало 1")
```

Comment: мне кажется, лучшим подходом было бы переименовать функцию, чтобы избежать коллизии имён

Comment: возможно, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1):

Убери "q" из `async def random(ctx,q):`.
Должно получиться `async def random(ctx):`